# Should we include the Bootstrap container class inside or outside of HTML semantic class article?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Should we include the Bootstrap `container` class inside or outside of HTML semantic class `<article>`?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>html</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <article>
                ...
            </article>
        </div>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Or,** this is recommended?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>html</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
    </head>
    <body>
        <article>
            <div class="container">
                ...
            </div>
        </article>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I place HTML5 semantic tags when using Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812296/where-should-i-place-html5-semantic-tags-when-using-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

With that in mind - you should keep the container on the outside. You can use grids to house the articles from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [HTML5 Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element):

> *The article element represents a complete, or self-contained,
>   composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in
>   principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in
>   syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper
>   article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget
>   or gadget, or any other independent item of content.*

AFAIK the "container" class does not give your code any kind of semantic markup. You can have articles inside articles, containers inside containers, articles inside containers, or containers inside articles. It just depends on what you want to show.

You can also have a look to [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/use-html5-sectioning-elements).

Comment: I agree with everything here - but as the question is about Bootstrap the `container` class takes on a special meaning so where it is in the HTML markup is serves more of a functional purpose and specific role. Agreed that it shouldn't interfere with the semantic markup either way in 'vanilla' HTML5.