# Where should I place HTML5 semantic tags when using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

There are at least 2 similar questions in here:

- [More semantic html 5 code with bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156922/more-semantic-html-5-code-with-bootstrap-3)
- [Should we include the bootstrap container class inside or outside of html semantic class article?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857028/should-we-include-the-bootstrap-container-class-inside-or-outside-of-html-semant)

But I am afraid nobody has answered properly none of them. The question is not to know if `section` can be used outside `main` or something like that. It is a simpler question in terms of the right practice when using HTML5 semantic tags with Bootstrap containers, rows, columns in your markup.

Basically, what is the best practice?

Option a)

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <article> <!-- INSIDE -->
   </article>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Option b)

```html
<article> <!-- OUTSIDE -->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</article>
```

Comment: A third option is `<article class="col-md-12"></article>`. And a fourth option is `<article class="container">...</article>`

Comment: So, it doesn't matter? I can choose whatever option I want - a,b c, d, etc - and is not going to mess in terms of styling practices? or there is not a best option of them in terms of organising your markup thinking ahead in terms of CSS styling? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: There really isn't a best practice here. The difference between `ab` and `cd` are just personal style, but the difference between `ac` and `bd` could have very different meanings in your CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `article` should encompass the content, and not the layout.

The difference is in whether the `article` IS a column, or whether the `article` HAS a column. Theoretically your CSS could interpret these differently.

I would personally prefer option "a" because it would separate the `article` as a unit of content, which you could move around in different layouts.

Answer (score 0):

An `<article>` element is an independent component of a web page. A `<div>` element is a generic element which does not create sectioning content and should mainly be used for styling.

The only semantic tag you have there is `<article>`.

However, a problem may arise if those div elements are styled as part of a grid. Since an article is supposed to be an independent, distributable part of the rest of the page, that grid, too, should be part of the article element only.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. I know both options can be used but is more like is there one option better than the other in terms of organising your markup for better styling practices?

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for telling me:)